# Google Plus public photo album shows in public news feed but not under photos

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I've created an album in Google Plus, and uploaded photos to it, publicly shared it to my profile, and users can publicly see the album from my profile, but it does not show up in the photos tab.

I've got several other albums created in the same way, and they work fine. Tried deleting and re-creating, no luck.

The URL of the album is: https://plus.google.com/photos/+AliciaSykes/albums/6039969757566122289

It should show up on the photos page, here, but it doesn't: https://plus.google.com/+AliciaSykes/photos

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. https://plus.google.com/+AliciaSykes/photos is your Highlights tab and Google has some magic algorithm that chooses what to put there. If you want to see all of your albums there are listed here https://plus.google.com/photos/+AliciaSykes/albums.